# get the values from recursive function and push them into array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have function which loops through all directories that i have, 
but i need to get `$timeMod`

of all that dirs in array, so i can find the dir with `max() $timeMod`, 
and i want to return that numbe, i need this number so i can use it as a var in my app.

This is my code so far:

```
public function loopThroughDirs($dir)
{      
    $timeMod = filectime($dir);
    $dateMod = ($timeMod) ? date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $timeMod) : ' - ';

    if($handle = opendir($dir)){
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ( $entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                if(is_dir($dir.$entry)){
                    $this->loopThroughDirs($dir.$entry.'/');
                } 
           }
        } 
        closedir($handle);
    } 

    return $timeMod;

 }
```

this returns only the last value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use array push! There are two ways to do this:

**First**

> array_push($array,$value);

**Second**

> $array[]=$value;